# Looking for a solid explanation on how aquire and release work with semaphores to sync threads

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to manipulate this program to print ":---)))))" repeatedly.
I understand that a semaphore is a way of controlling threads, and acquire essentially acquires a permit (reads) and release returns a permit back to the semaphore. (writes)

I've tried manipulating the number of permits when initializing the semaphores, but I am not understanding how to sync them together because I can't figure out how exactly the semaphores operate with how they acquire and release.

I am looking for a helpful explanation that pertains to Java in the context of only using semaphores, acquire and release and how they work together to properly put the threads "in sync"

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ThreadSync {
private static boolean runFlag = true; 
private static Semaphore canPrintC = new Semaphore(1);
private static Semaphore canPrintD = new Semaphore(0);
private static Semaphore canPrintP = new Semaphore(0);


public static void main(String [] args) {

    // Create and start each runnable 
    Runnable task1 = new TaskPrintC(); 
    Runnable task2 = new TaskPrintD(); 
    Runnable task3 = new TaskPrintP(); 

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(task1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(task2);
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(task3);

    thread1.start(); 
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    // Let them run for 500 ms
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    runFlag = false;

    thread3.interrupt();
    thread2.interrupt();
    thread1.interrupt();

}

public static class TaskPrintC implements Runnable {
    public void run() { 
        while (runFlag) {
            try {
                canPrintC.acquire();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s", ":");
            canPrintD.release();




        }
    }
}
public static class TaskPrintD implements Runnable {
    public void run() { 
        while (runFlag) {
            try {
                canPrintD.acquire();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s", "-");
            canPrintP.release();



        }
    }
}
public static class TaskPrintP implements Runnable {
    public void run() { 
        while (runFlag) {
            try {
                canPrintP.acquire();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s", ")");     
            canPrintC.release();


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The semantics of semaphores are well-defined, and have been since the 1970's.

Answer (score 0):

### Semaphore – to solve Producer/Consumer problem

A high level explanation of semaphore.

A semaphore contains a count indicating whether a resource is locked or available. Semaphore is a signaling mechanism (“I am done, you can carry on.”).  The resource itself may not be thread safe.

- Producer

  semObject.Post();   // Send the signal

> Increase the semaphore count by 1. If a thread is waiting on the
>   specified semaphore, it is awakened.[1]

- Consumer

  semObject.Wait();   // Wait for the signal

> When the semaphore count is zero, the thread calling this function
>   will wait for the semaphore. When the semaphore count is nonzero, the
>   count will be decremented by 1 and the thread calling this function
>   will continue.[1]

### Reference

[1] Massa, Anthony J., Embedded software development with eCos, Pearson Education, Inc., 2002

Answer (score 0):

Threads execute tasks and semaphores can help you to let tasks (or runnable objects) know each other's state (e.g. task A waits for input from task B and task B can signal task A that input is available). The difference between a task and a thread is important.

To stress this point, I have taken your example and made one runnable class that performs the task of printing a character a number of times (configured via variables in the constructor). To mimic the serialized behavior (tasks run after each other), the runnable is also aware of the next runnable that should perform the print task.

To complete the example I also ensured that the thread that is executing the main-method is aware of when the tasks have completed, so that the program stops at the proper time. A CountDownLatch is used in this case (a CountDownLatch is a very simple variation of a Semaphore).

The example below might be a bit hard to understand, but it shows some good practices (re-use code, using a stop-flag instead of interrupt, use an executor to run tasks, cleanup and stop tasks in case of error). It also shows how Semaphores can orchestrate the execution of tasks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ChainedSemaphoreTasks {

// amount of times chained tasks are executed.
static int MAX_CHAINED_LOOPS = 3;

// helper to let main-thread know when chained loops have been executed.
final static CountDownLatch MAX_LOOPS_REACHED = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String printChars = ":-)";
    int[] repeatChars = { 1, 3, 5};

    List<ChainedTask> tasks = buildTasks(printChars, repeatChars);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (ChainedTask task : tasks) {
        executor.execute(task);
    }

    try {
        // Trigger first task to start running.
        tasks.get(0).triggerPrintTask();
        // wait for loop to complete, but not too long.
        if (!MAX_LOOPS_REACHED.await(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Chained tasks loop did not complete within timeout.");
        }
        long waitStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor.shutdown();
        if (executor.awaitTermination(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("All tasks stopped within " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - waitStart) + " ms.");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not all chained tasks stopped within timeout.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // cleanup
        try {
            tasks.get(0).stop();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}

static List<ChainedTask> buildTasks(String printChars, int[] repeatChars) {

    List<ChainedTask> tasks = new ArrayList<ChainedTask>();
    int maxTasks = printChars.length();
    if (maxTasks != repeatChars.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount of repeats per pritn character must match amount of characters.");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
        ChainedTask task = new ChainedTask(printChars.charAt(i), repeatChars[i]); 
        tasks.add(task);
        if (i > 0) {
            tasks.get(i - 1).setNextTask(task);
        } 
    }
    // make last task trigger first task - creates an endless loop.
    tasks.get(maxTasks - 1).setNextTask(tasks.get(0));
    tasks.get(maxTasks - 1).setLastTask(true);
    return tasks;
}

static AtomicInteger chainedLoopsCount = new AtomicInteger();

static class ChainedTask implements Runnable {

    // Semaphore to trigger execution 
    Semaphore performTask = new Semaphore(0);
    // If stop is true, task must finish.
    // stop must be volatile to ensure updated value is always visible.
    volatile boolean stop = false;
    // The last task is responsible for stopping execution 
    boolean lastTask;
    // The next task to run after this task.
    ChainedTask nextTask;

    char printChar;
    int repeatAmount;

    ChainedTask(char printChar, int repeatAmount) {
        this.printChar = printChar;
        this.repeatAmount = repeatAmount;
        System.out.println("Created " + printChar + " / " + repeatAmount);
    }

    void triggerPrintTask() {

        performTask.release(repeatAmount);
    }

    void stop() {

        // first indicate to stop 
        stop = true;
        // then release a permit to pickup the stop sign.
        performTask.release();
        // also stop next task, unless this is the last task 
        if (!isLastTask()) {
            getNextTask().stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (!stop) {
                runTask();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Stopped " + printChar + " / " + repeatAmount);
    }

    void runTask() throws Exception {

        // wait for our turn
        performTask.acquire();
        // must check 'stop' after getting permit, see the stop-method:
        // first stop is set to true and then a permit is released.
        if (stop) {
            return;
        }
        // print text for loop-amount
        do {
            System.out.print(printChar);
        } while (performTask.tryAcquire());
        if (isLastTask()) {
            System.out.println();
            // check if we should stop
            if (chainedLoopsCount.incrementAndGet() >= MAX_CHAINED_LOOPS) {
                // since this is the last task, the next task is the first task.
                // stopping the first task will call the stop-method on all tasks, including this one.
                getNextTask().stop();
                // signal main-thread we are done.
                MAX_LOOPS_REACHED.countDown();
            }
            // Sleep for a long time to test what happens when last task hangs.
            // Should trigger the "cleanup" code in the main method.
            // Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        // trigger next chained task to run
        // this has no effect if next chained task was stopped 
        getNextTask().triggerPrintTask();
    }

    void setNextTask(ChainedTask nextTask) {
        this.nextTask = nextTask;
    }

    ChainedTask getNextTask() {
        return nextTask;
    }

    void setLastTask(boolean lastTask) {
        this.lastTask = lastTask;
    }

    boolean isLastTask() {
        return lastTask;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I Liked the variation with semaphore but the OP requested for a solid explanation on how acquire and release work with semaphore.